# Modify to reduce es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I want to collect all li with text content flexbox and reduce total time in second and return it. I done it, but how to rewrite the code to one single reduce function. The result should be a sum of data time in seconds

*html*

```
<li data-time="3:07">Flexbox Video</li>
<li data-time="5:59">Redux Video</li>
...
```

*js*

```
const listItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];

const flexBoxItem = listItems
    .filter(item => item.textContent.includes('Flexbox'))
    .map(item => item.dataset.time)
    .map(item => {
        let parts = item.split(':').map(i => parseFloat(i))
        return (parts[0] * 60) + parts[1]
    })
    .reduce((prev, next) => prev + next, 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would filter, and then reduce, since it's more functional and readable:

```js
const listItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];

const flexBoxTime = listItems
  .filter(item => item.textContent.includes('Flexbox'))
  .reduce((prev, item) => {
    const [min, sec] = item.dataset.time.split(':');
    return prev + (+min * 60) + +sec
  }, 0);
  
console.log(flexBoxTime);
```

```html
<li data-time="3:07">Flexbox Video</li>
<li data-time="5:59">Redux Video</li>
```

However, if you want to combine them as well because performance is an issue:

```js
const listItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];

const flexBoxTime = listItems
  .reduce((prev, item) => {
    if(!item.textContent.includes('Flexbox')) {
      return prev;
    }
    
    const [min, sec] = item.dataset.time.split(':');
    return prev + (+min * 60) + +sec
  }, 0);
  
console.log(flexBoxTime);
```

```html
<li data-time="3:07">Flexbox Video</li>
<li data-time="5:59">Redux Video</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using an old style for loop (yep, i don't answer the question):

```
 let result = 0;
 for(const item of listItems){
   if(!item.textContent.includes('Flexbox'))
      continue;
   const [mins, secs] = item.dataset.time.split(":");
   result += mins * 60 + +secs;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Minified and a bit optimized alternative:

```js
const time = [].reduce.call(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), (r, v) => v.textContent
    .includes('Flexbox') ? (v = v.dataset.time.split(':'), v[0] * 60 + +v[1] + r) : r, 0)

console.log(time)
```

```html
<li data-time="3:07">Flexbox Video</li>
<li data-time="5:59">Redux Video</li>
```